# In android Studio, Can't get Object from Server by ObjectInputStream.

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading

i'm now connecting android app and Server in my computer by using ObjectInputStream and output Stream. 
I used AsyncTask as Thread.

firstly, this is Server page that I wrote in Eclipse. 
I used ServerThread to do MultiThread.

```
class Server {

public Server() {
    ServerSocket server;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(8789);
        System.out.println("waiting");
        while(true){
        Socket client=server.accept();
        System.out.println("connected");

               ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
               ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
             ServerThread thread=new ServerThread(ois, oos);
              new Thread(thread).start();

                    }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Server();
}

     }
```

and this is serverthread.java

```
class ServerThread implements Runnable {
      ObjectInputStream ois;
      ObjectOutputStream oos;
      Database db=new Database();
      Command c;
      boolean exit=false;

        public ServerThread(ObjectInputStream ois, ObjectOutputStream oos) {
    this.ois=ois;
    this.oos=oos;

}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(!exit){

    try {
        c=(Command)ois.readObject();

        int type=c.getCommandValue();
        Object []args=c.getArgs();
        switch(type){

        case Command.LogIn:
            String id=(String)args[0];
            String pw=(String)args[1];
            System.out.println("ID&pW from android : "+id+","+pw);
            Client cli=db.searchOne(id, pw);
            if(id.equals(cli.getId())&&pw.equals(cli.getPw())){
                System.out.println("Login success");
                c.setMessage("success");
                System.out.println("Command to Android : "+c);
                oos.writeObject(c);
                oos.flush();
                System.out.println("well done");

            }else{
                System.out.println("로그인 실패");
                c.setMessage("로그인 실패");
                oos.writeObject(c);
            }
```

break;

```
   `Protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button button_logIn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.logIn);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        /*ConnectThread th=new ConnectThread();
            Log.d(TAG, "스레드부름");
            th.start();*/

            BackgroundTask bk=new BackgroundTask();
            bk.execute();
        }
    });
       button_logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText tf_id_forLogin = (EditText) findViewById                    (R.id.tf_id_LogIn);

            EditText tf_pw_forLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_pw_LogIn);
            String id = tf_id_forLogin.getText().toString();
            String pw = tf_pw_forLogin.getText().toString();
            Command c = new Command(Command.LogIn);
            Object args[] = {id, pw};
            c.setArgs(args);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id pw to pc server : " + id + "," + pw + c.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                ***Log.d(TAG, "try login");***
                oos.writeObject(c);

                c = (Command) ois.readObject();
                Log.d(TAG, "received : "+c);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received : " + c.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (c.getMessage().equals("success")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "로그인 성공했다. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "로그인 실패했다. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```

`
**finally, this is android studio's code. 
I can see weel this log message  ***Log.d(TAG, "try login");***
but after that, it dosen't apper any message to logcat. 
It dosen't work any of ois.readObject and I can't find reason why. 
no error message appeared.**

Comment: Once had a similar issue, where it blocked while trying to open input stream. Solved it by reversing the order, that's, first opening the output stream. No idea, but maybe you experience the same problem.

Comment: In any case use a debugger, to check if the program hangs anywhere.